# Progress bar with ajax and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, user-interface

i saw many examples - all looked pretty much the same to - make a progress bar (while uploading a file - until it finishes uploading)
so i tried this code -

```
$.ajax({
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete);
                $('.progress').css({
                    width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                });
                if (percentComplete === 1) {
                    $('.progress').addClass('hide');
                }
            }
        }, false);
        xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                console.log(percentComplete);
                $('.progress').css({
                    width: percentComplete * 100 + '%'
                });
            }
        }, false);
        return xhr;
    },
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/echo/html",
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {}
});
```

*ignore the url and the data - the example is on the xhr part*

so when i tried to use this i saw that many people say that it no longer supported with jQuery 1.9.3+.
anybody has an idea how i can do it?